# How to create one single row at a time in native JS?

Tags: javascript

I am currently creating a random group generator. The first part of this project requires me to make a table. This table can take in two inputs per row, a first name and a last name.

What needs to happen is that after a first and last name is inputted into a row, a new row should be created just below it. When a row is filled out, two IDs should be made: `firstNamerowNumber` and `lastNamerowNumber`. This is because I would like this table to be able to extend onward until my Chromebook breaks.

**Problem**: However, not just 1 row is being made at a time. Let's say you have 1 row filled out, 1 new row is added (that's good). Now say you have 2 rows filled out, 2 new rows are added (bad).

**Question**: How can I make it so that only 1 row is added at all times after a `change` event?

Note: For clarity, each first and last name need unique IDs because they will be stored in arrays and then used to create random groups later, making it important that the correct first name goes with the correct last name.

```js
const inputArticle = document.querySelector('#input-article');
const outputArticle = document.querySelector('#output-article');
const table = document.querySelector('#table');
const addRowButton = document.querySelector('#addRow');
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit');

let names = [];
let rowNumber = 0; //Maybe I could try to use a for loop? I couldn't get that to work, though

function addRow() {
    let row = table.insertRow(-1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    let firstNameInput = document.createElement("input");
    let lastNameInput = document.createElement("input");

    firstNameInput.type = "text";
    firstNameInput.setAttribute('id', `firstName${rowNumber}`);
    cell1.appendChild(firstNameInput);
        
    lastNameInput.type = "text";
    lastNameInput.setAttribute('id', `lastName${rowNumber}`);
    cell2.appendChild(lastNameInput);

    table.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if (firstNameInput == null || lastNameInput == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (firstNameInput.value && lastNameInput.value) {
            addRow();
            rowNumber++;
            let firstName = firstNameInput.value;
            let lastName = lastNameInput.value;
        }
    })   
}

function submit() {
    let confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you have all of the names?");

    if (confirmation) {
        inputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
        outputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
}

addRowButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addRow();
    addRowButton.disabled = true;
})

inputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
outputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit);
```

```css
#input-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

table {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

th {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 800;
}

input {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#buttons {
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
}

#submit {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 84%;
}

#output-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Random Group Generator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <article id="input-article">
            <table id="table" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name:</th>
                    <th>Last Name:</th>
                </tr>
            </table> <br>

            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article id="output-article">
            Output
        </article>

        <script src="try.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An ID should be unique in the DOM, you can't use the same ID for each row. That will brake things.

Comment: That is why the rowNumber variable is there. After each firstName and lastName, there will be a number, making a unique ID.

Comment: Ahh I see, sorry, didn't see that yet.

Comment: Don't name anything `submit` in a form if you ever expect to submit it using script

Comment: Have ONE click event listener on the table OUTSIDE any other event listener. Right now you add event listeners EVERY time you click

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I did, I have a working code now thanks to you and the other users on this post. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way you're checking if you should add a new row that is braking your logic.

I'd tackle this like so:

```
function addRow() {
    // unchanged code

    firstNameInput.addEventListener('change', onRowChange);
    lastNameInput.addEventListener('change', onRowChange);
}

function onRowChange(e) {
  if ([ ...e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children ].every(c => c.children[0].value)) {
      rowNumber++;
      addRow();
  }
}
```

So we add 2 eventlisteners to both the inputs, then we call `onRowChange` where we

1. Get the second parent of the input (the table row)
2. Loop through the children, so we check both first and last name (and maybe more later)
3. If both of them have a truely value

   1. Bump rowCounter (could be replaced with a checker)
   2. Call `addRow()`

---

Updated Demo:

```js
const inputArticle = document.querySelector('#input-article');
const outputArticle = document.querySelector('#output-article');
const table = document.querySelector('#table');
const addRowButton = document.querySelector('#addRow');
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit');

let names = [];
let rowNumber = 0; //Maybe I could try to use a for loop? I couldn't get that to work, though

function addRow() {
    let row = table.insertRow(-1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    let firstNameInput = document.createElement("input");
    let lastNameInput = document.createElement("input");

    firstNameInput.type = "text";
    firstNameInput.setAttribute('id', `firstName${rowNumber}`);
    cell1.appendChild(firstNameInput);
        
    lastNameInput.type = "text";
    lastNameInput.setAttribute('id', `lastName${rowNumber}`);
    cell2.appendChild(lastNameInput);

    firstNameInput.addEventListener('change', onRowChange);
    lastNameInput.addEventListener('change', onRowChange);
}

function onRowChange(e) {
  if ([ ...e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children ].every(c => c.children[0].value)) {
      rowNumber++;
      addRow();
  }
}

function submit() {
    let confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you have all of the names?");

    if (confirmation) {
        inputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
        outputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
}

addRowButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addRow();
    addRowButton.disabled = true;
})

inputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
outputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit);
```

```css
#input-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

table {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

th {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 800;
}

input {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#buttons {
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
}

#submit {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 84%;
}

#output-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Random Group Generator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <article id="input-article">
            <table id="table" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name:</th>
                    <th>Last Name:</th>
                </tr>
            </table> <br>

            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article id="output-article">
            Output
        </article>

        <script src="try.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @0stone0 The downvote is presumably for not using event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding more and more event listeners to the table element, just add a change event listener to both inputs in the newly-created row.

```js
function handleChange() {
    // this is the original code in the event handler
    if (firstNameInput == null || lastNameInput == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (firstNameInput.value && lastNameInput.value) {
        addRow();
        rowNumber++;
        let firstName = firstNameInput.value;
        let lastName = lastNameInput.value;
    }
}
firstNameInput.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
lastNameInput.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
```

Comment: [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/19bf7sy0/)

Comment: Better: Have ONE event listener on the TABLE but outside the click event listener

Comment: @mplungjan Sure, this answer is just showing the minimal amount of changes. You can always add your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. IDs are specific. Use getElementById
2. Use ONE event listener assigned OUTSIDE any other event listeners
3. No need for the addrow button
4. Use valid HTML, then we can drop the external rowCounter and just count rows.
5. Use focus to be able to fill the table without the mouse

I added the submit handling

```js
const inputArticle = document.getElementById('input-article');
const outputArticle = document.getElementById('output-article');
const table = document.querySelector('#table tbody');
const mySubmitButton = document.getElementById('mySubmit');

function addRow() {
  let rowNumber = table.rows.length;
  let row = table.insertRow(-1);
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  let firstNameInput = document.createElement("input");
  let lastNameInput = document.createElement("input");

  firstNameInput.type = "text";
  firstNameInput.setAttribute('id', `firstName${rowNumber}`);
  cell1.appendChild(firstNameInput);

  lastNameInput.type = "text";
  lastNameInput.setAttribute('id', `lastName${rowNumber}`);
  cell2.appendChild(lastNameInput);
  firstNameInput.focus();
}

const onRowChange = (e) => {
  const inputs = table.querySelectorAll('input');
  if ([...inputs].every(input => input.value.trim() !== "")) addRow();
};

const mySubmit = (e) => {
  let confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you have all of the names?");
  if (confirmation) {
    inputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
    outputArticle.innerHTML = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr'))
      .map((row,i) => Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('input'))
        .map(input => input.value)
        .join(' '))
      .join('<br/>');
    outputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
};
table.addEventListener('change', onRowChange);
inputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
outputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
mySubmitButton.addEventListener('click', mySubmit);

addRow(); // Initial call to add the first row
```

```css
#input-article.hidden {
  display: none;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

th {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: 800;
}

input {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 5vmin;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#buttons {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
}

#submit {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 84%;
}

#output-article.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article id="input-article">
  <table id="table" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <th>Last Name:</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table> <br>

  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="mySubmit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</article>

<article id="output-article">
  Output
</article>

<script src="try.js"></script>
```